# how to generate a click event on a position on the screen

Tags: java, android, onclick

**What I am having**: I have a activity where i am displaying a dialog.

**What i am trying to do**: I am trying to perform a click event on the yes button on dialog after it is shown. (**Without touching it**)

**Question**: Is it possible to perform it, if so any sample

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RelativeLayout activity_main;
    float centreX,centreY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity_main=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        setDialog();

    }

    private void setDialog() {

        int mWidth= this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int mHeight= this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


        simulateClick(mWidth+200,mHeight+200);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Woahhhh")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.testing.touchevent.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can create a custom dialog with custom layout(with ok and cancel button) and use **buttonObject.performClick();** to achieve the result

Comment: May I ask what the ultimate purpose of this? I don't mean to pry, but unless there's a particularly good reason to simulate a click I'd generally just directly call the code that would run had a click actually happened. I'm guessing that there's something special going on for you which makes this infeasible, though?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the button which you want to click from Dialog Interface, then perform click event on it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Woahhhh")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
```